# How to split a single field into two separate fields using logstash filter plugins

Tags: logstash

Here is the sample log "where there is_ a will.their is a way"

I need "where there is" stored in one string , and "their is a way" in another string , that is want to  split based on hyphen and dot , in Logstash .

I tried using split,but getting stuck.

Please help me.

Comment: If you could show your *conf* please? So you've got the string in a single field already?

Comment: Here is my log : rose is a flower_and;flower is a rose

Comment: Here is my conf  :   input{

file{
 path => ["/home/user/Documents/milliclogs/trial/split1.log"]
 start_position => beginning
 sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
 }

}

filter {

 grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:message1}" }
     }
 
  mutate
      {
         split => {"message1" , "_"}
         add_field => {
          "name1" => "%{message1[0]}"  
          "name2" => "%{message1[1]}"
                      }
      }

Comment: mutate
    {
        split => {"name2" , "."}
        add_field => {
           "name3" => "%{name2[0]}"
           "name4" => "%{name2[1]}"
                     }
  
       remove_field => ["name2"]
       remove_field => ["name3"]
    }  
   }

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}